# Mail Merge over the Internet

Tags: java, oracle, reporting-services

The company I work for (international mailing house) currently provide a service as follows:

Receive flat file address data, sort and analyse to mark country and postcodes/zip codes, and then output to hardcopy address carriers which comprise of a PPI (printed postage impressions), undeliverable return address, recipient address, logos and artwork pertaining to the publication or mail item. They also can provide PDF documents to send to customers. Note the PPI can change for each country/region.

The business would like to be able to provide this as a service on the web preferably using Oracle/Java.

They need to get away from the architecture of sending the address carriers as PDF documents to customers as the file size grows exponentially depending on the number of addresses. They would like to be able to send the graphics once to the client machine and then merge the address data as the address carriers are printed thus cutting down on network traffic.

What reporting tools primarily in Oracle/Java are available that will be able to support this over the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a tool which produces hard copy mail or email over the Internet?

It sounds like you want a ERP or CRM system ?? if so you can look at these http://java-sources.net/open-source/erp-crm

Comment: No the end result will always be a hardcopy

Answer (score 2):

This is way-late, but possibly useful to others finding this question.  There is a "mail merge cloud service" called [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which can perform mail merges from templates and email deliveries.  It works at a lower level than a CRM system so is probably only useful if you need to control the process yourself.